# How to make hydrogen peroxide into gel

Tags: home-experiment

How to make hydrogen peroxide into a gel or just simply really thick and it has to be able to be in your mouth?

The only thing i have came up with is (Gelatins). 
What should i use?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of vegetable gums, such as carageenan, pectin and gum arabic, and man-made [methyl cellulose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methyl_cellulose) which *might* be compatible with low concentrations of $\ce{H2O2}$, which you can determine easily. Any impurities, particularly transition metals, may make $\ce{H2O2}$ decompose, so it might be best to keep the gelling agent and peroxide separate until just before use.

If for oral use, [this site](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8247815) suggests 0.75% to 1.5% solutions, one quarter and one half the strength of the common antiseptic **N.B. $\ce{H2O2}$ bleach is much stronger and is *not* for oral use.** Note that there *are* [dangers](http://www.intelligentdental.com/2010/07/09/so-can-hydrogen-peroxide-be-used-as-mouthwash-safely/) with use of peroxide as a mouthwash.

Answer (score 0):

gels are of different types and shelf lives. If you are thinking of a true gel (water gel) then natural gums like guar, carrageenan, pectin, gum Arabic, etc are not useful. The gel will break down within no time. There are no material that can give hydrogen peroxide a good viscosity with shelf life more than 7 days.

Comment: So that sounds reasonable then, to mix the gel at the time of use.  So making a thicker gel with pectin or xantham gum and applying it should be fine.